# Adding image in tableViewCell after clikcing from camera

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I have tableview  cell and buttons as well as imageView inside cell, what I am doing is clicking the image from the camera and adding it to image view, problem is when setting image view all the cells are getting same image.

Comment: provide your trial code.

Comment: @SagarBhut check edited

Comment: in open camera button press at time which method call?

Comment: @SagarBhut it takes to click image view controller from where m passing uiimage to this tableviewcell.

Comment: that passed image store/replace in your array right?

Comment: no its like this ////  @IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any) {
      
    
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
        let gvc: GuidelinesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "guides") as! GuidelinesViewController;
        gvc.catImage = capturedImageRef
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController =  gvc
    }

Comment: not readable...

Comment: @SagarBhut added in question

Comment: table in GuidelinesViewController ?

Comment: @SagarBhut yes it is

Comment: catImage image change when click in open camera?

Comment: @SagarBhut yes everytime its a new image.

Comment: so image in all cell are changed. because when you change catImage image that is used in all the cell so it's change in all cell..

Comment: @SagarBhut what is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want every cell to has an image then create an array

```
var images = [UIImage]()

cell.imageView?.image = images[indexPath.row]
cell.openCamera.tag = indexPath.row
```

When the button clicked , open imagePicker then update the array of images at index of the clicked button tag  to the new image then reload the table

Comment: I believe suggesting to use `prepareForReuse` for this purpose is not best based on documentation `For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state.`

Comment: it is just replacing images in cell, what i want is if i am clicking image from button[0] , image should go in image[0] and if m clicking from cell 2 button[1] , image should go in image[1] , it should not replace all images of cells

Comment: @Sh_Khan oh okay, I edited the question to show how i am passing image from another view controller

Comment: your image has 2 cell s how you would set the other cell image t0 ??

Comment: you need an else statement to set the image when ndexPath.row != index

Comment: @Sh_Khan I want to set that dynamically when i click picture.

Comment: @Sh_Khan okay i ll try this , you can edit your answer, after this get works i ll upvote.